# How to connect two django model query sets

Tags: python, django, django-models

When a list of strings(representing tags) are sent to a function, it retrieves tags that are in DB and also crates tags that are not found in db.

I need to then combine those two into one queryset and return but when I tried to connect the two querysets by using +, it raises error.

How can I connect two querysets?

```
# Separate one in DB and not in DB
tags_found_in_db = Tag.objects.filter(name__in = tag_strings)
name_of_tags_found_in_db = [tag.name for tag in tags_found_in_db]
tags_not_in_db = list(set(tag_strings) - set(name_of_tags_found_in_db))

# Bulk Create
tags_to_be_created = []

for new_tag_name in tags_not_in_db:
  tags_to_be_created.append(
    Tag(name = new_tag_name)
  )
new_tags = Tag.objects.bulk_create( tags_to_be_created )

# > TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "QuerySet") to list
return new_tags + tags_found_in_db
```

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

No need to combine anything, just return `tags_found_in_db` as Querysets are lazy.

However, if *absolutely* necessary to do so use `.union` method Queryset object to combine Querysets.

## Notes

`bulk_create` does not return a Queryset object, making `.union` even less practical for your use case.

## References

Django Querysets are lazy: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy

Django Queryset Union: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#union

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests one of the parameters above is QuerySet and you need to convert it to list. Check which one of them is a QuerySet and why it is not converted to a list.

Also instead of returning:

```
return new_tags + tags_found_in_db
```

You can return Tag.objects.all() - it should return the same result. If you really need to concatenate Querysets [check this article](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/06/20/django-tip-5-how-to-merge-querysets.html)